Word press wp-admin redirecting to aws lb
We've hosted word press on AWS EC2 instance (Private subnet), and it's attached to AWS application load balancer(Internet facing), then it's attached to AWS cloud front, our website is pointing to AWS cloud front.
Requests follows this: User --> www.example.in --> AWS cloud front --> AWS ALB --> AWS EC2 instance.
In the application load balancer we do have the one listener with two rules.
listener with port 80 and forwarding to backend rules (default rule and another rule /blogs/*)
Our word press is on /var/www/html/blogs.
So whenever the user hit www.example.in is working fine, www.example.in/blogs/ also working fine but when we're trying to access the www.example.in/blogs/wp-admin it's redirecting to application load balancer.
Hmmm… can't reach this page alb-example-app-lb-xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com refused to connect
I read the one of the solution if we add multiple behavior it will works, even i tried but nothing is working for me.
as per my knowledge we need to add one for default behavior and another behavior for /blogs/* then it should for all subfolders and files.

.htaccess file for redirection
[root@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX blogs]# cat .htaccess 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blogs/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Force HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

added this lines inside wp-config.php.
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.in/blogs');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.in/blogs');
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"];
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT"];
}

even we've updated our db with siteurl and home.
MariaDB [wordpress]> SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' OR option_name = 'home';
+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| option_name | option_value                      |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| home        | https://www.example.in/blogs |
| siteurl     | https://www.example.in/blogs |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [wordpress]> 

we've created the certificate with *.example.in www.example.in and attached it to on the AWS cloud front.
Note: we're offloading the certificates in AWS cloudfront level it self.
Our end goals is that we want to access the wp-admin page from our domain.
When we hit the www.example.in/blogs/wp-admin we need to get the login page and able to login.
